# Simple AJAX MySQL Query Load

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've asked this in a different post but finally realized what it is I'm actually trying to ask.

Is there anything simple that will allow me to load 5 rows from a MySQL table and then with an AJAX driven button, show 5 more, etc, etc (sorta like Facebook does with their 'View Older Posts' button (I am using PHP).

Comment: think in terms of paginating sql queries. Then use those same ideas, but instead of creating a link to the next page of results, do it from an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve all of your data and store in DIVs, placing 5 records in every div and separating divs by id and then use javascript to show div on each click.

Comment: Let's say the query is pulling 1000 rows, will that dramatically affect load time? Otherwise, this seems like the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JS var that stores your current record status.

Every time you load the 5 records, pass this value through ajax to your script to use in the MySQL "LIMIT $start, 5 "portion.  Everytime you load, increment the variable by 5 and pass it back to your PHP page.  It'll grab the next five, limiting 5 records.